# Class<SpringExtension> cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, maven, junit

I am trying to migrate a JUnit 4 test to JUnit 5. Eclipse does not recognize SpringExtension.class : Class cannot be resolved. I use Spring 5.2.2 and Maven in the project.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to project > Maven > Update project... > Force Update of Snapshots / Releases .